# About float in CSS

Tags: css, css-float

I'm having some troubles with the 'float' in css. 
I have a wrapper div with a width of 960px.I want to add 5 child-div in it with the width of 960 / 5 = 192px. And this is what I've got:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/R6bsw.png

This is my lines of code. Can anyone tell me what's wrong with them?

**HTML**

```css
#overall-info h1 {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1em;
}

.box {
  width: 192px;
  height: 192px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  background-color: aquamarine;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<section id="overall-info">
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Info</h1>
    <div class="box">

    </div>

    <div class="box">

    </div>

    <div class="box">

    </div>

    <div class="box">

    </div>

    <div class="box">

    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Try to check there is no border width. Set margin,padding to 0.

Comment: Consider switching to using flex-box instead.

Answer (score 1):

> About `box-sizing:border-box`:
>
> The width and height properties (and min/max properties) includes content, padding and border, but not the margin.

**For Fix it:**

So, you must use `box-sizing:border-box;` because width of `.box`(192px) includes `.box` border width (1px for border-left and 1px for border-right).

**if you don't add** `box-sizing:border-box`,it will be added 2px(1px for border-left and 1px for border-right) to each `.box`,in the other words width `.box` gets width (192px + 2px = 194px).

```
* {
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
    width: 960px;
}


#overall-info h1 {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 1em;
}

.box {
    width: 192px;
    height: 192px;
    border: 1px solid green;
    background-color: aquamarine;
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<section id="overall-info">
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Info</h1>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

For each sub-boxes you have 1px of border which successively adds up to the total width.

So the container should have a width of (192+1+1)*5 = 970 and not 960 if you want all your sub-boxes to be contained on one line. You can also suppress the border or use a sub-box width of 190 (190+1+1=192)

Furthermore keeping 1px of free width space for the container can also help

Answer (score 0):

Your 1px borders are adding-up to the width space of your boxes.

set in your css:

```
* {box-sizing: border-box; }
```

you can also use percentages widths btw to welcome yourself into the responsive era ;)

```
.box {
  float: left;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: aquamarine;
  border: 1px solid green;
  width: 20%;
  height: 100px;
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing

in which `box-sizing` set to `border-box` is used to account borders, paddings and width into the inner box model width of the targeted element.

If you plan to support IE7 (which is not needed today) than you'll have to manually subtract the `border-width` from the element `width`.

Comment: @ehsan You are using `padding` which adds up to the element `width` hence you need to alter the `box-sizing`

Comment: @ehsan aah I thought you are the OP, may be he was typing this answer at the same time so...

Comment: However, this answer does explain why and not just a "copy & paste this" (which could have been a comment instead)